# MQ - delete all messages from a queue

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

I'm new to MQ programming with java.
For my Integration tests, I would like to clean up the destination queue before posting any messages to it. Is there any option in MQ-Java to delete all messages in a queue in one go?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a WMQ PCF program to clear messages in queue in one go. PCF classes provide an interface to administer WMQ programatically. There is a sample, PCF_ClearQueue.java that demonstrates clearing messages from a queue.

The sample is located (on Windows platforms) \tools\pcf\samples directory. More information on clear queue can be found [here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/topic/com.ibm.mq.ref.adm.doc/q087070_.htm).

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to runmqsc then use the MQSC command called: CLEAR QLOCAL

Note: If an application has the queue open then that command will fail and PCF commands will fail too.  Hence, you will need to get all messages from the queue one at a time.  You can download a Java program called **EmptyQ** from http://www.capitalware.com/mq_code_java.html that will do the trick.